# How to print value of a variable (which can be "-n" or "-e") in bash?

Tags: bash

How to print "-n", "-e" or "-neeenen" from bash (without a newline at the end, without invoking of external programs)?

`Q="-n"`

`echo -n "$Q"`   # fail

`echo -- "$Q"` # fail

`cat <<< "$Q"` # fail, also starts external program

`printf -- '%s' "$Q"` # success, <s>but starts external program</s>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, `printf` is a builtin, so no external program is invoked.

> ```
> $ help printf 
> printf: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
> ```
>
> printf formats and prints ARGUMENTS under control of the FORMAT.
>   FORMAT
>       is a character string which contains three types of objects: plain
>       characters, which are simply copied to standard output, character
>   escape
>       sequences which are converted and copied to the standard output, and
>       format specifications, each of which causes printing of the next
>   successive
>       argument.  In addition to the standard printf(1) formats, %b means
>   to
>       expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument, and %q
>       means to quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input.
>       If the -v option is supplied, the output is placed into the value of the
>       shell variable VAR rather than being sent to the standard output.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo -en \\x2Dn
```

Comment: No, I'm looking for a way to print a value of variable. (Refining the question)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the correct and more portable way is to use `printf`, however this works:

```
$ Q='-n'
$ echo -ne '\0'"$Q"
```

but it fails if you have backslash sequences that you want to print literally:

```
$ Q='-n\nX'
$ echo -ne '\0'"$Q"
-n
X
```

when what was wanted was "-n\nX". In this situation, this works:

```
$ echo -n $'\0'"$Q"
-n\nX$                 # (no newline, so prompt follows on the same line)
```

but it doesn't for `Q='-n'`!

What if we want to print the literal string with `printf`?

```
$ Q='-n\nX'
$ printf "$Q"
-bash: printf: -n: invalid option
$ printf -- "$Q"
-n
X
$ printf "%s" "$Q"
-n\nX$                 # (no newline, so prompt follows on the same line)
```